# What does "in two months’ time" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have the book "if life's a game these are the rules". In the Epilogue, the writer said:

> if you did enjoy reading this and want to improve your life, do yourself a favor and set yourself a reminder to **read this book again in two months’ time**.

What does "read this book again in two months’ time" mean? Does it mean "read this book over and over during two months’ time", or "two months’ time after first read, I should read this book again"

Answer (score 2):

Your second guess - "2 months after the first reading" - is correct.

You might have guessed this from context - "set yourself a reminder".  You don't need a reminder for something you do continuously.

Comment: I think its a fair question; its really quite colloquial